# Is id="nodeName" reserved in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using:

```
<span id="nodeName"></span>
```

in my html, then let jquery do:

```
$("#nodeName").html("someString");
```

Then, the console says that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'toLowerCase'
```

After I change the id, it works all right. So, is there any reserved id?

Comment: It isn't reserved, but using it can have odd side effects in some browsers because `nodeName` is also a property on nodes in javascript, and giving an element an id will (in those specific browsers that have this functionality) automatically generate a property on the window and the node's parent for that id.

Comment: @KevinB But how could it pose a problem as an **`id`**?

Comment: @Ian just selecting the element is enough to cause the error http://jsfiddle.net/6HWPr/1/

Comment: heck you don't even have to select it. http://jsfiddle.net/6HWPr/2/

Comment: @KevinB I understand that, I believe the OP and you that it's causing a problem, I'm just wondering **why**. FYI - while having an element with a specific `id` sets a property on `window`, it **doesn't** set a property on its parent node. You might be thinking of setting a `name`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any other id people should avoid?

Comment: submit/reset for submit/reset buttons is a common mistake

Comment: @KevinB  I guess I won't mess up with submit/reset:) Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is failing in the following function:

```
acceptData: function( elem ) {
    // Do not set data on non-element because it will not be cleared (#8335).
    if ( elem.nodeType && elem.nodeType !== 1 && elem.nodeType !== 9 ) {
        return false;
    }

    var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

    // nodes accept data unless otherwise specified; rejection can be conditional
    return !noData || noData !== true && elem.getAttribute("classid") === noData;
}
```

Specifically on the call `elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()`, when `elem === window`. This gets called when you include jQuery in the page, even if you never select that element in your Javascript.

The reason is that jQuery does a check to see which elements can handle `data-attributes` once jQuery is ready. During that check it calls the acceptData function on the `window` element.

This in the most recent versions of jQuery 1, since version 1.8.0 and up to and including the latest 1.10.1. The bug seems to have been introduced by the following change in jQuery 1.8:

> $(element).data(“events”): In version 1.6, jQuery separated its internal data from the user’s data to prevent name collisions. However, some people were using the internal undocumented “events” data structure so we made it possible to still retrieve that via .data(). This is now removed in 1.8, but you can still get to the events data for debugging purposes via $._data(element, "events"). Note that this is not a supported public interface; the actual data structures may change incompatibly from version to version.

The window is passed into `jQuery._data` as `cur` on line 2939 in [version 1.8.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js), in order to check for the internal "events" data on the window object. This happens when jQuery triggers the `$(document).ready` `$(window).ready` events. Since window is not a DOM node acceptData shouldn't be called on window at all.

```
handle = ( jQuery._data( cur, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] && jQuery._data( cur, "handle" );
```

[I created a bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14074)

Comment: I just found this too, but didn't know how it was called. Can you show where/how the `acceptData` is called?

Comment: I see you're trying to debug jQuery. You should totally drop that and... ah, screw it.

Comment: +1 the issue is caused when the call to `window.nodeName` returns the `span` element where it should have returned `undefined`. I am going to stop there and not going any further.

Answer (score 16):

No, [almost any string is a valid ID](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute). And this only happens when you include jQuery (a 1.xx version, not a 2.xx one).

More details :

- the code works, as in "it changes the innerHTML"
- as soon as you include jQuery, even if you don't use it, you have an error in `acceptData`, when the dom is ready, but after the callback you passed to `$(document).ready` was executed.

It's a jQuery bug. Why it happens seems to be due to `window.nodeName` being defined to this element (which doesn't have a toLowerCase method as it's an element)  by the fact the element with this id exists. It seems to be OK in jQuery 2.02.

Comment: Good answer! OP you should file a bug report to jQuery. Does this also happen in jQuery 2 by the way?

Comment: No, I am going to upvote this because something is obviously very wrong with jQuery.

Comment: What i'm wondering is *why* is this happening. it's failing within jquery when elem.nodeName is being used, but that shouldn't ever actually cause this problem unless it's being used on window, and window doesn't have a nodeName anyway.

Comment: @dystroy I stopped upvoting it, "You last voted on this answer 7 mins ago Your vote is now locked". It's telling me I can't upvote it any more. I would if I could.

Comment: @KevinB It seems to happen after executing `.html` > http://jsfiddle.net/SnGs5/ <  debugging the code right now. I am holding my vote until I find why. This answer doesn't say that clearly.

Comment: @Vega KevinB's comment on the OP proves it doesn't require any jQuery code to be run. Simply including the element and the jQuery library, the error occurs: http://jsfiddle.net/6HWPr/2/

Comment: @KevinB Your comments has lot more information than the answers here.

Comment: $(window).trigger could theoretically cause that to happen, but i don't see that used.

Comment: @KevinB How about `$(document).ready()`? I'm not sure why `window` would be looked at, but it is something that executes by itself

Comment: It's once more proven it was a bad id to set `window.someId` when an element with this id exists...

Comment: `document.nodeName` returns `#document`, not the span, so that can't be the culprit http://jsfiddle.net/6esdn/1/

Comment: @KevinB No, I understand that `document.nodeName` wouldn't be the culprit, but I'm trying to think of the source of calling `acceptData`, and the only place I can find is within `trigger`. The only thing I can think of automatically being executed is `$(document).ready`'s promise and triggering handlers for it. Again, I don't know why it would be looking at `window`, but that's the only "automatic" thing I can think of

Comment: Actually, yes one of the two causes of it is originating from the dom ready codebase, the other is probably from the same place.

Comment: Ah, i see it. The event is propagated to the window, at which point it attempts to acceptData on the window, but it can't get the nodeName. Does 2.0.2 support the old `.on("ready"` syntax? if not, that would explain why it works in 2.0.2 properly because there would be no need to .trigger it

Comment: there we go. I can forcefully trigger it in 1.10 using `.trigger(randomevent)`, but not in 2.0.2, i assume there's some oldIE support baked in to 1.10 that requires `acceptData` to be used on window. switch between 2.0.2 and 1.10.1 http://jsfiddle.net/6esdn/3/